# C++ Memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, free, memory-leaks

Hi I have this following code, it take nodes from slaveQueue and preload to preload1 and preload2, But the memory is always increasing. I assume it should be released after I call dfs since all the memory should be freed after the local function returns and I checked that pop() function will also free the memory ? so I wonder where is my memory leak? THanks

```
    queue<Graphnode> *preload1 = new queue<Graphnode>;
    queue<Graphnode> *preload2 = new queue<Graphnode>;
    for(int n = windowWidth; n > 0; n--)
    {
        if((*slaveQueue).empty())
        {
            //cout <<"fffffffffffff"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        (*preload2).push((*slaveQueue).front());
        //cout << (*slaveQueue).size()<<endl;
        (*slaveQueue).pop();
    }
    int preload1No =0;

    while(!(*preload2).empty())
    {
        preload1No++;
        *slaveroot = (*preload2).front();
        (*preload2).pop();
        if(!(*slaveQueue).empty())
        {
            (*preload2).push((*slaveQueue).front());
            (*slaveQueue).pop();
        }
        dfs(*slaveroot,goal,totalDepth,*preload1,*preload2,checkfile);
        if(preload1No>windowWidth)
        {
            (*preload1).push(*slaveroot);
            (*preload1).pop();
        }
        else
        {
            (*preload1).push(*slaveroot);
        }
        cout<<(*preload1).size()<<"\t"<<(*preload2).size()<<endl;
    }
    delete slaveroot;
    delete preload1;
    delete preload2;
    delete slaveQueue;
```

Comment: for each `new` you need a `delete` and for each `delete` you need a `new`. Your code looks fine because your not pass a copy of a your pass a pointer to a.

Comment: Better still - read about RAII, avoid `new` when you can

Comment: Did you perhaps learn Java or C# first?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will make a copy of the pointer `a`, but not of the memory that `a` points to. So there is no memory leak here, and thus nothing to free.

Comment: Since I wrote this answer, the text in the question has been COMPLETELY changed, and this answer makes very little sense to the code in the question).

Answer (score 1):

The `a` in `func1` is pass by value, which means its on the stack. Hence it won't create *any* memory leak. It is released when `func` exits.

Comment: so if there is any memory leak, I should not think about the variables in any function?

Comment: You must use a profiler, and use tools like valgrind to hunt for memory leak. Remember to `delete` every `new` data and you'll almost always be safe. Also use STL to help you manage the complexity of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not explicitly allocating any memory in `func1`, and call no function that does that, then there is no memory leak. All you are copying into the function is a pointer. The copied pointer itself is on the function's stack, and gets popped along with everything else in the function's scope once the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as shown has no memory leaks.

Comment: How often can you say that!?

Answer (score 0):

It does create a copy of `a` on the stack. But that memory is recovered as soon as the function returns.

If you have a memory leak, that is likely caused by code not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `a` to your function, a copy of `a` itself is what gets passed. When the function exits, that copy of `a` gets destroyed. The memory that `a` points at isn't copied at all in your code.

Your code leaks one byte of memory<sup>1</sup> because you're calling `func1` in an infinite loop, so the `delete a;` will never execute. When most people talk/think about memory leaks, however, they're thinking of "progressive" leaks -- ones that leak more memory the longer the program runs.

---

1. If you want to get technical, what it leaks is one minimum-sized block from your memory manager. That'll typically be larger than 1 byte, but exactly how much larger will depend on the implementation.